# In the given sentence, what is the meaning of shot

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

Rasheed shot her a sidelong glance. He made a sound between a sigh and a groan, dropped his legs
from the table, and turned off the radio. He took it upstairs to his room. He closed the door.

Comment: It’s in here: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shoot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this instance, I believe it should be interpreted as

"Looked at, quickly"